# The longitude limits of mercator projection?

Tags: gis, mercator

I understand why there is a limit in the latitude for the mercator projection, but how about the longitude, from the theory I assume it would be [-180, 180].

However, from several map application's source code I have seen. They tried to limit the longitude between [-177, 177].

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Internet tells me that this projection

> extends from 180° W to 174° W and is centered on 177° W